# JSF and Bean Validation group

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

I use JavaEE 7 (JSF 2.2, Bean Validation 1.1...) and primefaces 5.1 in WildFly 8.1 runtime

I want to use different validation groups according to the pressed button. A save button associated with a small number of constraints and a submit button associated with a larger number of constraints.

The bean validation groups seem to be what I need but I have some issues with the web interface.

I wan't that the invalid inputs appear in red according to the validation mode : save or submit

So I made 3 interfaces :

```
public interface LifeCycleValidation {}
public interface Save extends LifeCycleValidation {}
public interface Submit extends Save {}
```

I annotate fields using BeanVal with the appropiate group in the model object

```
@Size(min=3, max = 300, groups = Save.class)
@NotNull(groups = Save.class)
private String title ;

@Size(min = 3, max = 5, groups = Submit.class)
private List<String> keywords ;
```

I made some methods in the JSF managed bean

```
private final String formIdPrefix = "bookEditForm:" ;

public void save() {
    save(Save.class) ;
}

public void submit() {
    save(Submit.class) ;
}

private void save(Class<? extends LifeCycleValidation> groupClass) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory() ;
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Book>> violations = validator.validate(this, groupClass);
    violations.stream()
            .forEach(violation -> addErrorMessage(formIdPrefix+violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage()));
    if(violations.isEmpty()) {
        // save
        addInfoMessage("","sucess") ;
    } else {
        addErrorMessage("",violations.size()+" error(s)") ;
    }
}

private void addErrorMessage(String id, String msg) {
    addMessage(id,FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Error",msg) ;
}

private void addInfoMessage(String id, String msg) {
    addMessage(id,FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Info",msg) ;
}

private void addMessage(String clientId, FacesMessage.Severity severity, String summary, String detail) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientId, message);
}
```

The messages display correctly if the id of the input correspond to the path of the property but the input aren't red

```
    <h:form id="bookEditForm">
        <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true"/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">

            <p:outputLabel value="title" for="title"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{book.title}" id="title"/>
            <p:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="title"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="keywords" for="keywords"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{book.keywords}" id="keywords" converter="converter.ListString"/>
            <p:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="keywords"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{book.save()}" update="@form"/>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{book.submit()}" update="@form"/>

    </h:form>
```

(in my exemple the model and the controller is in the same class, it was just a test)

I try an other solution using f:validateBean validationGroups
So I made ValidationMode enum:

```
public enum ValidationMode {
    SAVE(Save.class), SUBMIT(Submit.class);

    public final Class<? extends LifeCycleValidation> cl ;

    private ValidationMode(Class<? extends LifeCycleValidation> cl) {
        this.cl = cl ;
    }
}
```

and put it in the JSF managed bean:

```
private ValidationMode validationMode ;

public void setValidationMode(String validationModeTitle) {
    this.validationMode = ValidationMode.valueOf(validationModeTitle);
}

public String getValidationGroups() {
    if(validationMode==null) {
        return ValidationMode.SAVE.cl.getCanonicalName() ;
    }
    return validationMode.cl.getCanonicalName() ;
}
```

and try to set the appropriate mode in the actionListener of ther commandButton

```
    <h:form id="bookEditForm">
        <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true"/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">

            <p:outputLabel value="title" for="title"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{book.title}" id="title">
                <f:validateBean validationGroups="#{book.validationGroups}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="title"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="keywords" for="keywords"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{book.keywords}" id="keywords" converter="converter.ListString">
                <f:validateBean validationGroups="#{book.validationGroups}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="keywords"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{book.save()}" actionListener="#{book.setValidationMode('SAVE')}" update="@form"/>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{book.submit()}" actionListener="#{book.setValidationMode('SUBMIT')}" update="@form"/>

    </h:form>
```

but that doesn't work

The I think of writing my own jsf validator but I don't know how to implement the validator to validate the field according to the right group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found something, I trigger the setValidationMode when an onmouseover occured like that the validation mode is set before the action: save or submit is called

```
        <h:panelGroup layout="span">
            <p:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{book.setValidationMode('SAVE')}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{book.save()}" update="@form"/>
        </h:panelGroup>            
        <h:panelGroup layout="span">
            <p:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{book.setValidationMode('SUBMIT')}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{book.submit()}" update="@form"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

so you have nothing to do in the controller

```
private ValidationMode validationMode = ValidationMode.SAVE ;

public void setValidationMode(String validationModeTitle) {
    this.validationMode = ValidationMode.valueOf(validationModeTitle);
}

public String getValidationGroups() {
    return validationMode.cl.getCanonicalName() ;
}

public void save() {
    // save
    addInfoMessage("","saved") ;
}

public void submit() {
    // submit
    addInfoMessage("","submited") ;
}
```

---

Edit

here is the clean and complete MVC solution with the progressbar calculated in bonus :

the view:

```
    <h:form id="bookEditForm">

        <p:progressBar value="#{bookBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" id="progress"/>

        <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true"/>

        <p:panelGrid columns="3">

            <p:outputLabel value="title" for="title"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{bookBean.book.title}" id="title">
                <f:validateBean validationGroups="#{bookBean.validationGroups}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="title"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="keywords" for="keywords"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{bookBean.book.keywords}" id="keywords" converter="converter.ListString">
                <f:validateBean validationGroups="#{bookBean.validationGroups}"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="keywords"/>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGroup layout="span">
            <p:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{bookBean.setValidationMode('SAVE')}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{bookBean.save()}" update="@form"/>
        </h:panelGroup>            
        <h:panelGroup layout="span">
            <p:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{bookBean.setValidationMode('SUBMIT')}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bookBean.submit()}" update="@form"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:form>
```

the controller:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable {

    private ValidationMode validationMode = ValidationMode.SAVE;

    private Book book ;

    public BookView() {
        book = new Book() ;
    }

    public void setValidationMode(String validationModeTitle) {
        this.validationMode = ValidationMode.valueOf(validationModeTitle);
    }

    public String getValidationGroups() {
        return validationMode.cl.getCanonicalName() ;
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void save() {
        // save...
        addMessage("",FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Success","Infos saved") ;
    }

    public void submit() {
        //submit...
        addMessage("",FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Success","Infos submitted") ;
    }

    private void addMessage(String clientId, FacesMessage.Severity severity, String summary, String detail) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientId, message);
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory() ;
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        int nbConstraints = validator.getConstraintsForClass(Book.class).getConstrainedProperties().size() ;
        int nbViolations = validator.validate(book, Submit.class).size();
        return 100 - (nbViolations*100) / (nbConstraints) ;
    }
}
```

the model:

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @NotNull(groups = Save.class)
    @Size(min=1, max = 140, groups = Save.class)
    private String title ;

    @NotNull(groups = Submit.class)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 5, groups = Submit.class)
    private List<String> keywords ;

    // getters and setters
}
```

ValidationMode, LifeCycleValidation, Save and Submit are the same as in the question

And OmniFaces seems to have a nice solution :
http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean
Could be interesting...

Comment: no keyboard post support? try use actionListener on p:commandButton.

Comment: do setValidationMode in actionListener doesn't work because setValidationMode need to update all f:validateBean in the page, that is not happening between actionListener and action

Comment: and do setValidationMode  in onmouseover of p:commandButton doesn't work neither and I don't know why...